# Need time window checker function

Tags: php

TO check if current time falls in specified window I've a very useful function in Javascript:

```
var time_ranges = [
            {
                start: "12:00:00",
                end: "12:11:00"
            },
            {
                start: "16:00:00",
                end: "16:03:00"
            },

        ];
        return check_time_in_window(time_ranges); //checks if current time falls in any window period
```

Is there any ready-made & tested function in PHP or similar kind?

Comment: Yes, PHP has a class called [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: That code doesn't check anything. It creates an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this. It will check if today is less than max time and more than min time.

```
$today = new \DateTime();
echo  $today >= (new \DateTime('16:03:00')) && $today <= (new \DateTime('23:00:00'));
```